# How to send a hardcoded complex json respnse in Golang

Tags: json, go

I am trying to send some complex data as JSON response to one of my rest APIs as follows:

```
   y := "[ { \"region\":\"North America\", \"countries\":[{\"country\" : \"United States of America\",\"states\"" +
    ":[\"California\", \"New York\", ], }, {\"country\" : \"Canada\",\"states\" : [\"Ontario\", \"Quebec\",], }] }," +
    "{\"region\": \"Asia\",\"countries\": [{\"country\" :\"China\",\"states\" : [\"Fujian\", \"Guangzhou\" ]}, {" +
    "\"country\" : \"Japan\", \"states\" : [ \"Kyushu\", \"Hokaido\" ] }  ]  }]"

    x, err := json.Marshal(y)
    fmt.Println(err)

    c.JSON(200, string(x))
```

In response I get:

```
"\"[ { \"region\":\"North America\", \"countries\":[{\"country\" : \"United States of America\",\"states\":[\"California\", \"New York\", ], }, {\"country\" : \"Canada\",\"states\" : [\"Ontario\", \"Quebec\",], }] },{\"region\": \"Asia\",\"countries\": [{\"country\" :\"China\",\"states\" : [\"Fujian\", \"Guangzhou\" ]}, {\"country\" : \"Japan\", \"states\" : [ \"Kyushu\", \"Hokaido\" ] }  ]  }]\""
```

How do I get rid of these trailing `\` in the response? If I remove them from `y`, the code does not compile.

Comment: Try `c.JSON(200, string(y))`. `y` shouldn't need `json.Marshal`.

Comment: You can make the JSON string a lot more readable by wrapping it in backticks `\`` - then you don't need to escape all the quotes.  Much cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have the JSON encoded string, you do not need Marshal, you just need to send down the string. By Marshalling here you are encoding your JSON string into a JSON string so Go is escaping it. Just send down the string if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is more concerned about the backslashes in his JSON string than the unnecessary `json.Marshal` (more on that below)

***You can use `strconv.Unquote` on your JSON string to clean up the back slashes***.

`s, _ := strconv.Unquote(y)
fmt.Println(s)`

You don't need to Marshal `y`, which turns it into bytes then convert it back into a string. You can pass `y` right down to `c.JSON`

You want to use Marshal when you have a `struct` that you want to bundle into JSON.